# exec.Command: Scanner stops before command is complete when cmd includes a sleep

Tags: go

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c",
        `for i in $(seq 1 10000); do
          echo  '{"Name": "Bob", "Age": 32}'
          sleep $(( ${RANDOM}%5))            # <<<< Stops before reading all lines when uncommented
        done`,
    )
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    printOutput(stdout)

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}

func printOutput(r io.Reader) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    var x = 1
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(x, scanner.Text())
        x++
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("reading input:", err)
    }
}
```

When `sleep $(( ${RANDOM}%5))` is commented, the Scanner reads all the 10K lines and those get printed. However, when it is uncommented the program exits before it prints out all the lines. Probably, the scanner exits prematurely because it interprets the empty pipe as EOF.

Is there a way to completely read the stdout of the command until it has exited (and not terminate prematurely)?

Comment: It works well on my macOS Catalina, but `sh --version` shows `GNU bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid `sh` syntax but expects `sh` to be `bash`. While this is the same on some systems it is not on others. On these it v´breaks with:

```
arithmetic expression: expecting primary: " %5"`
```